# How to check if file exists in asterisk

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

I am currently working on asterisk.
I have to perform some action if the file exists, and if it does not, than I will have to play the message that file not exists.

So how can I check the If the file exists in asterisk dialplan

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Even if Muhammad Salman Farooq mentioned it before, here an example:
We want to play a personal prompt or a generic, as a fallback.

```
same => n,Set(exists=${STAT(e,${ASTDATADIR}/sounds/custom/user-${EXTEN}.wav)})
```

The [`STAT` function](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+18+Function_STAT) returns 1 if the file exists and 0 if not. In this case we are checking some files we want to play using the `Playback` function. Therefore, we have to define the whole file path. Use the `ASTDATADIR` variable to keep your dialplan system independent.

To play the generic or the personalized file use this:

```
same => n,Playback(custom/user-${IF($[ ${exists} = 1 ] ? ${EXTEN} : generic)})
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do this

```
 same => n,System(test -e /path/to/file)
 same => n,GotoIf($["${SYSTEMSTATUS}" = "SUCCESS"]?alabel)
```

Don't forget the file extension on the file name

Answer (score -1):

In the dial-plan, you can execute an asterisk AGI script (perl for example) to check if the file exist then assign a boolean variable which can be retrieved in dial-plan later. Then in the next dial-plan action, you can manage how it acts (play a sound file) based on set variable.. You can reference asterisk perl agi here: http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+perl+library

Comment: No, AGI is not the choice for us, our AGI is placed on another machine, and if that machine goes down, than our dail-plan should work smartly. I have found solution , the STAT() function of asterisk had done job for me.

Comment: I did not know that function, it is interesting :)